# Format of v in the JVM modified UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, jvm

In the JVM specification, in [the description of the modified UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7), it states the format of `v` for the "two-times-three-byte format":

> This means supplementary characters are represented by six bytes, u, v, w, x, y, and z
>
> Table 4.14. v: 1010 (bits 20-16)-1

Since `v` is 8 bits, it means that `(bits 20-16)-1` has to be 4 bits. How can the `-1` shrink `bits 20-26` from 5 to 4 bits?

(Supplementary question: is there any reason to say "two-times-three-byte" rather than "six-byte"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unicode code points](http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_point) are ranged from `U+0000` to `U+10FFFF`.

Values greater than `U+FFFF` are called *supplementary code points*. Their binary representation is `uuuuuxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` (21 bits), where `uuuuu` is between `00001` and `10000`.

In UTF-16 supplementary code points are encoded by [surrogate pairs](http://unicode.org/glossary/#surrogate_pair) as described in [3.9 Unicode Encoding Forms, D91](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404). That is, `uuuuuxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is represented by two 16-bit characters:
`110110wwwwxxxxxx 110111xxxxxxxxxx`, where `wwww = uuuuu - 1`.

`00001 ≤ uuuuu ≤ 10000`, therefore, `0000 ≤ wwww ≤ 1111`

Now, modified UTF-8 encodes supplementary code points as if they were two characters: high surrogate and low surrogate. Each of these surrogate characters is represented by 3 bytes in UTF-8. Hence *'two-times-three'* figure.